# Scala immutable Map like datastructure that has constant/effective constant lookup

Tags: json, scala, data-structures, immutability, scala-collections

In designing a JSON AST for Scala, we realised we hit a problem (which can be described in greater detail here https://github.com/json4s/json4s-ast/issues/8), where ideally we would like to represent a `JObject` (JSON object) with a Map structure that either preserves ordering for its keys OR is is sorted by key using a default `Ordering` that has either constant or effective constant lookup time.

The reason why we need something that either preserves ordering, or guarantees the keys are sorted, is that when someone serializes the JValue, we need to make sure that it always outputs the same JSON for the same JValue (most obvious case is caching JValue serializations)

The issue is that Scala stdlib doesn't appear to have an immutable Map like datastructure that preserves/orders by key with a O(c) or O(eC) lookup time (reference http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

Does anyone know if there is an implementation of such a datastructure in Scala somewhere that follows the Scala collections library (or even if such a datastructure exists in general)?

Comment: There is SortedMap but I can't find anything about it's performance. If you really don't find anything though you can make your own with a HashMap and an Array/HashMap that maps an index to a key.

Comment: SortedMap is an abstract trait. Its default implementation in Scala is a `TreeMap`, which has log lookup (instead of c/eC)

Comment: Why you don't want to store ordered keys sequence separately? 
Something like `(Seq[String], Map[String, AnyRef])`.

Comment: Mainly due to memory, this is an generic JSON AST datatype, which could be holding huge amounts of JSON data.

Also unless I am mistaken, it would mean that we would have to create our own collection that implements the `Scala` sortedMap interface anyways, because we expect users to treat the `type` inside `JObject` as a standard map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort in constant time in general, so using an `Ordering` is right out.

And there aren't actually any immutable data structures I'm aware of that let you add and delete in arbitrary spots with constant performance (best you can get is `O(log N)` though some people like to pretend that if the base on the logarithm is large enough it's "effectively constant").

So what you're asking for isn't possible.

But as a fallback, `TreeMap` isn't bad for sorted keys.  It's pretty efficient for a `O(log N)` solution.

For keys in the correct order, you in general need to maintain three maps: index to key, key to index, and key to value.  Index to key should be a `TreeMap` so you can walk in order.  The others can be whatever.  The essential idea is that when you want to add a key-value pair, you increment the index and add (index -> key) to the first map and (key -> index) to the second.  Then when you walk in order, you walk along the index-to-key map and look up in the key-value map.  When you delete by key, you find the index with the key-to-index map so you can delete it from the index-to-key map also.

Comment: Do you have any idea if the `TreeMap` performance is similar to `Vector` in terms of lookup/creation?

According to the scala docs, `Vector` is effective constant lookup, where as `TreeMap` is just log (not sure if they actually mean O(log N)). I suppose if its actually O(log N)), then its pretty much the same as `Vector`.

If thats the case, it also means the the docs are wrong

Comment: @mdedetrich vector is a hierarchical data structure, so lookup and update is O(log(N)). It is just that the branching factor is so high that people consider it effectively constant for typical sizes. For your case, just go with a s.c.i.TreeMap for now.

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation with other people, it seems we will maintain 2 data structures (a vector and a map, i.e. https://github.com/json4s/json4s-ast/issues/8#issuecomment-125025604) which is essentially what @Aivean mentioned. Performance is a bigger concern than potential memory usage.

If you need ordering, a `TreeMap` is indeed the fastest structure, which does have O(log(n)), without ordering you have you standard immutable `Map`, which is O(n(log(n)) (Haskell also has Data.Map, which works similarly).

Thanks for the answers!